# Java keypairs - private & public - I only have private

Tags: android, java, keystore, keytool

I'm having some problems packaging an app because the jarsigner keeps telling me this:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: MyApp.  MyApp must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

I generated the keystore using the command:

```
 keytool -genkey -keystore myAppKeystore.keystore -alias myApp
```

then filled in the rest of the information as it prompted.

When I checked the app using this command I found:

```
keytool -keystore myAppKeystore.keystore -list -v
```

It said something like this, and it seems to only say private key:

```
Alias name: myApp
Creation date: 06-Sep-2012
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: ......etc
```

I'm sure it will be something really obvious, but what am I missing? I was under the impression the previous command created a keypair? Not just the private key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a [public key certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate). You can use `keytool` to generate certificate requests to a certificate authority and import certificate replies. Perhaps all you need is a [self-signed certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html).

Comment: Thanks, I understand a lot more now :) after reading I need a trusted certificate so self signing won't do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a certificate for the key pair, with 'keytool -selfcert ...'. Better still, generate a CSR and get your CA to issue a code signing certificate.